# Using lmfit minimize to fit a 3D line on a dataset of 3D points

Tags: python, 3d, scipy, minimize, lmfit

I am using lmfit minimize to fit a 3D line on a dataset of 3D points.

```
from lmfit import minimize, Parameters, report_fit,fit_report, printfuncs
import numpy as np

#Parameters of parametric equations:  
#x = p[0] + p[1]*t;
#y = p[2] + p[3]*t;
#z = t;
params = Parameters()
params.add('x0',   value= 1)
params.add('x1',   value= 1)
params.add('y0',   value= 1)
params.add('y1',   value= 1)

#Function to be minimized - sum of distances between the line and each point    
def fun(params,x,y,z):
    x0 = params['x0'].value; x1 = params['x1'].value 
    y0 = params['y0'].value; y1 = params['y1'].value
    d = 0  

    v0 = np.array([x0, y0, 0.0])
    v1 = np.array([x0+x1, y0+y1, 1.])
    for point in range(len(x)):           
        p = np.array([x[point], y[point], z[point]])
        d += np.linalg.norm(np.cross(v1-v0,v0-p))/np.linalg.norm(v1-v0)  
    return d


result = minimize(fun, params,args=(x,y,z)))
result.params.pretty_print()
print(fit_report(result))
```

The error is TypeError: Improper input: N=4 must not exceed M=1.

I understand it is due to having only 1 residual (distance) and 4 parameters, but this is what I need. I want to optimize 4 parameters to get the minimum sum of distances.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that in your case `fun` returns a scalar. That's fine for some of the methods, but as you correctly stated `least_squares` needs an array. I think rewriting your objective function such that it returns an array should solve this - look at the description and examples [here](http://lmfit.github.io/lmfit-py/fitting.html#fit-func-label).

Answer (score 0):

Seems its a method issue.

> The objective function should return the value to be minimized. For the >Levenberg-Marquardt algorithm from leastsq() or least_squares(), this >returned value must be an array, with a length greater than or equal to >the number of fitting variables in the model.

Using Nelder, I get results. 
Not correct ones though. So still unsure about the code.

Answer (score 0):

For using Levenberg-Marquardt minimization (the default method for `lmfit.minimize()`), you should return the ndarray of distances.  That is, do not make the least-squares sum yourself.   By returning the full array (all observations of distances for a particular set of parameter values), you allow the fitting algorithm to better explore the effect of the parameters on the quality of the fit.

Comment: Thanks! I accepted the other answer as it was first but you are absolutely right.